My application which is hosted on EC2 instance which is in private subnet is not connecting with RDS which is in private subnet
My application is hosted in Ec2 instance(windows) and MySQL database in AWS RDS. Since both Ec2 instance(windows) and RDS MySQL both are in same vpc same region and on private subnet, my application is not connecting with RDS database.
Tried by adding security group but it doesnt help. Please provide suggestion to connect my Ec2 instance and RDS. So that my application should connect with database.

You need to add ingress rules to your subnets that allow a tunnel from EC2 to RDS on MySql port. Also, since this is a windows server, you need to check the defender firewall on that box to ensure that type of traffic can pass in/out of the server.
